# Using environment variable with parens, like %ProgramFiles(x86)% in a compound IF-statement raises unexpected errors

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt

I tried the belowed scenarios with/without `delayedExpansion` (edited: Squashman explained in the comments that delayed expansion isn't needed)

I receive unpredictable errors when I try to set an environment variable which uses `!ProgramFiles(x86)!` or `%ProgramFiles(x86)%`

Example:

```
@echo off
rem With or without this, with/without "!" or "%", fails on "SET"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

if exist "!ProgramFiles(x86)!\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer" (
    set INSTALLVS=!ProgramFiles(x86)!\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer
)

echo !INSTALLVS!
```

Result:

> d:\test>runbatch.cmd
>   !\Microsoft was unexpected at this time.

Adding quotes works (as in `SET="%ProgramFile..."`, but then I run into trouble later, having to remove the quotes when combining paths), or a temp variable works:

```
@echo off
rem Works correctly
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set INSTALLTMP=!ProgramFiles(x86)!\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer

if exist "!INSTALLTMP!" (
    set INSTALLVS=!INSTALLTMP!
    set INSTALLTMP=
)

echo !INSTALLVS!
```

This happens:

- When `delayedExpansion` is on or off
- Whether in either case I use `%` or `!`

Does *not* happen when:

- Outside `IF` statement
- The `SET` param is quoted: `SET foo="%ProgramFiles(x86)%"`, but this adds the quotes to the value of that param

What am I doing wrong / misunderstanding here?

Comment: Have you tried with `set "INSTALLVS=!ProgramFiles(x86)!\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer"`, quoting the operation and not the value?

Comment: You don't have delayed expansion enabled with a `SETLOCAL` command.  Nor do I see why you would need to use that variable with delayed expansion.

Comment: @squashman, I do have it in the main script. It is necessary because parts contain nested if statements that depend on one another. I'll update the question, copy /paste error, thanks. The error also shows without delayed expansion, btw.

Comment: @MCND, that seems to work! But it doesn't answer the question, why does this only go wrong with `!ProgramFile(x86)!` (my guess: it's a bug in Windows, and it struggles with the parentheses)

Comment: @Abel, you do not need to use delayed expansion for the `ProgramFiles(x86)` environmental variable.

Comment: @Abel - the closing quote is kidnapped by the IF command and then the cmd does not know what to do with the rest of the set expression. Putting it in quotes prevents this.

Comment: @Squashman, I see what you mean, because it doesn't change (i.e., it is static). But still, with or without, the same error.

Comment: @npocmaka: what closing quote? The variable itself does not contain a quote, and there is no quote on that line (but yes: putting the SET-assignment in quotes does solve the problem, I just don't understand why)

Comment: Abel, @npocmaka, meant to say the parentheses from the Program Files (x86) variable is closing the IF command because you do not have the set operation within quotes like MC ND noted in the very first comment of this question.

Comment: @Squashman, ahaaa! Now it makes sense! Yes, trying any scenario with some other variable that contains `)`'s has the same effect. At least that's a logical explanation and it fits with MCND's solutation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the closing parenthesis, which closes the `IF`-block. Whether or not you have delayed expansion on doesn't matter.

- Some statements, like `echo`, `rem`, `::` work without a problem when they contain a closing parenthesis.
- Most other statements, like `set`, `copy`, `goto`, `md` etc don't work, and a closing paren that is not quoted, will close the IF-block.
- Compound statement (like `echo hello > foo(32).txt`) don't work for the same reason.
- If the closing parenthesis is part of an environment variable's name that you use it is likely to short-circuit the IF-block too
- Closing parens that are part of a nested IF or DO block are safe, nesting is allowed

Solution is to place the closing parenthesis in quotes if the command allows it, or escape it, i.e. : `!ProgramFiles^(x86^)!` (only works reliably with [`enableDelayedExpansion`](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)).

For instance:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

if exist "!ProgramFiles(x86)!\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer" (
    set "INSTALLVS=!ProgramFiles(x86)!\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer"
)

echo !INSTALLVS!

if exist "!ProgramFiles(x86)!\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer" (
    set INSTALLVS=!ProgramFiles^(x86^)!\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer
)

echo %INSTALLVS%

setlocal disabledelayedexpansion

if exist "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer" (
    set "INSTALLVS=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer"
)

echo %INSTALLVS%

pause
```

Output

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: @Abel: IMHO You are not understanding the point here. The closing parenthesis does NOT "disrupts" the syntax of the IF-statement. A closing parenthesis _CLOSES_ the IF statement no matters where it is placed. If there is any reason to place a closing parenthesis inside the IF (for example, in a `set /A x=(a+b)/c` arithmetic expression) then such a parenthesis will close the IF, so it is necessary to either enclose it in quotes or `^)` escape it... BTW it is not necessary to escape a left paren.

Comment: @aacini, yes, that's how I understood it. 'disrupt' may be a poor choice of words, I meant to say it disrupts your intention as a programmer. And yes, I know the left paren doesn't need escaping, but I think this is clearer for readers of the code. Btw, enclosing in quotes is not always possible (i.e. with echo statement), so having both workarounds in your toolbox is necessary.

Comment: @Abel: Ah! And the `^)` escape method works always (no matter Delayed Expansion)

Comment: @Aacini, just tested again. Copy the last block, with the two `%ProgramFiles(x86)%` in it, remove quotes, add `^)`. It will not raise an error, the if-statement evalutes to true, but inside the block, the environment variable's value will be evaluated as empty. So, it will fix the closing-paren issue, but changes the parsing of the environment variable inside the if-block for some reason, hence "it does not work without delayed expansion". Also, looks like not all statements with unquoted `)` fail the if-block. `echo` works, `copy` does not, for instance.